# Can't Populate Materialize Select Options with Javascript Initialization

Tags: javascript, materialize

I have been having the hardest time populating a Materialize select box via Javascript. I am designing a Google web app, during which, when a user selects a particular company a select box is initialized and populated with a list of employees that work for that company. I have tried this every way I can think of, basing my syntax off of a previous Materialize autocomplete field that I thought would be initialized and passed an options object virtually the same way, but this did not work. I have included my Javascript, HTML, and the object I am trying to pass. Also, I am nearly done with this project and I have not used any JQuery to this point and would really prefer to not to if possible.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include("pageCSS"); ?>

</head>
   <body>
      <div class="input-field">
         <select id="pocSelect">
             <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Point of Contact</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAIKd0URSDHKo781LAxniLUQKE-cJ-a3qg&libraries=places&callback=initMap&channel=GMPSB_addressselection_v1_cABC" async defer></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <?!= include("pageScripts"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
 function updateClientInfo(clientDataObj){

        clientObj = clientDataObj[0];

        var options = {};
        var selectOptions = {};
        options = clientDataObj[1];

        options.forEach(function(v){

          selectOptions[v] = false;

        });

        var pocSelect = document.getElementById("pocSelect");
        M.FormSelect.init(pocSelect, {options: selectOptions});
      }
</script>
```

```
selectOptions = {Greg: false, Jason: false, Avery: false, Rebecca: false, Terry: false}
```